# Can't access fields from Address object in Triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, address

I'm trying to access fields from an address object retrieved from a Trigger, however it seems like I only get null values from it.
If I use the same code from a SOQL query instead of a Trigger, It works.
Is there some limitation on triggers? I wasn't able to find anything on the dev guide.

Thanks,

```
trigger myTrigger on Account (before Update) {
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        Address myAddr = acc.BillingAddress;
        System.Debug(myAddr.getStreet()); // is Null
    }
}

public with sharing class SomeClass {
    public static void someMethod() {
        Account acc = [SELECT Id, BillingAddress FROM Account LIMIT 1];
        Address myAddr = acc.BillingAddress;
        System.Debug(myAddr.getStreet()); // is not Null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship values are not populated in `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.old`. You will need to use the individual fields, such as `BillingStreet`. To use the compound fields, you'd have to query the database for them.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I thought compound fields would be queried, it means I can't get the update BillingAddress Field in a "before update" (Or the old one in a "after update") right ?

Comment: @loris Correct. It's better just to use the individual fields in this case.

Comment: Put a slightly different way: BillingAddress is a compound field, and I think of it as not really existing - just the individual fields. So change your BillingAddress reference to BillingStreet and use that directly. Repeating for every individual field is annoying, but necessary.

Comment: Thank you both !